# Get Latest Version from Artifactory Nuget Repository

Tags: nuget, artifactory, jfrog-cli

In JFrog Artifactory, how do you perform a GET request for the latest version in a Nuget repository.

We have tried the below method but I don't think its meant for Nuget repos. GET

`GET http://localhost:8081/artifactory/ivy-local/org/acme/[RELEASE]/acme-[RELEASE].jar`

The snippet is from https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact

Answer (score 0):

As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501770/retrieve-the-latest-from-a-generic-repository-from-artifactory-using-curl), you will first need to deploy the artifact as a layout.

It is mentioned in the documentation here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+Artifacts