# Retrieve the latest from a generic repository from artifactory using Curl

Tags: open-source, artifactory, artifact

I'm using Artifactory 6.1.0 OSS version.

When I try to retrieve the latest zip that is located in a Generic repo, I can't get the file to download.

i searched the web and found:
[[image: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact[1]]

But It's only relevant for the pro version of Atrifactory.

Anyone encounter this problem before?

Comment: Are you sure you are using version 1.17.1 of Artifactory?

Comment: I'm sorry!
you're right, that's the version of the jfrog-cli, i wanted to download. i'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

You will need to deploy the artifact according to layout, as explained [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+Artifacts)

You just need to do it once for a directory, and subsequently all artifacts in the directory can be downloaded using the -[RELEASE] syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as i said, i'm using the OSS version AKA free version of artifactory, so i don't have there the kind of repo that i need (uploading npm and using Generic Repository). and as far as i've seen there is no "Deploy according to layout" check option there.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to achieve that out of the box, you will need to use features only available in Artifactory Pro: [Layouts](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts), [Get latest version REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonLayout).